# Surrounding bigger div with smaller divs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've got a mindblowing task... for me. Here is the [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/EkFEh/)  of what I'm trying to achieve.

Code in the fiddle:

HTML

```
<div id="container">
<div class="smallsq">Small Square</div>
<div class="bigsq">Big Square</div>
<div class="smallsq">Small Square</div>
<div class="smallsq">Small Square</div>
<div class="smallsq">Small Square</div>
<div class="vertsq">Vert Square</div>
<div class="smallsq">Small Square</div>
<div class="smallsq">Small Square</div>
<div class="smallsq">Small Square</div>
<div class="smallsq">Small Square</div>
<div class="smallsq">Small Square</div>
<div class="smallsq">Small Square</div>
<div class="smallsq">Small Square</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
width:500px;
height: 500px;
background: #ccc;
display: block;
}
.bigsq {
width: 20%;
height: 20%;
background: red;
float: left;
display: block;
}
.smallsq {
width: 10%;
height: 10%;
background: green;
float: left;
display: block;
}
.vertsq {
width: 10%;
height: 20%;
background: blue;
display:block;
float: left;
}
```

*In short:*

I've got 3 square sizes. I really need to surround the Big Box and Vert Box with Small boxes  but notice **NO MATTER WHAT THEIR POSITION IS (eg. two smalls before big, or big-small-small-big-ver, or four smalls-vert-small-big, etc)**. Not only to the right of the Big & Vert boxes but and in left should have a Small boxes too, so there'll be no empty rows like in my example... Please notice also that I don't want to use eg. "small holder" to hold my small boxes like I've been read recently for the only solution of this problem. 
I have no problem to use jquery or js or everything you propose to reach the Goal :)

P.S: The image of the result wanted: [image]

Comment: don't circumvent site rules with `'code'` highlighting. You can't add a fiddle without the code for a reason.

Comment: tried to hyper your link, but SO said to me `jsfiddle links must be accompanied by code` : P

Comment: Your question would be better understood if you've provided a picture of the result you want. (Didn't downvote)

Comment: It's simple! The result should be a BIG BOX surrounded with small boxes no matter where inside "sea" of small boxes I will put a Big Box - it must be surrounded with boxes.

Comment: @Spoonk I _think_ I understand what you mean. If you provide a picture, I'll know what you mean.

Comment: This is like something you would see in a logic puzzle magazine...A big box is surrounded by a series of small boxes, but only if the big box is two boxes away from a vertical box that is also surrounded by smaller boxes next to a box of boxes with a box inside.

Comment: RobSedwick - I'm sorry but If I knew how to do it, I wouldn't ask here... I'll try your method. Thanks

Comment: for the CSS part It's worth a look into 'flexbox' for a job like this - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes

Comment: @sabof - I attached an image :)

Comment: +1 This is a good question @Spoonk. I think the downvotes are because of the jsfiddle without posting any code as SO alerted me to when trying to make an edit.

Comment: +1 The problem is interesting, and a solution could potentially be useful in other contexts.

Answer (score 0):

**[The Masonry Layout](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=masonary%20layout&oq=masonary%20layout)** ?

My answer comes from a search and what you are trying to achieve is **[explained here](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-masonry-layout/)** really well.

As expected, to achieve this goes beyond the capabilities of just CSS ( though perhaps [boxflex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes) will get us there / near for a CSS only solution )

From that article are a number of links to javascript libraries.

- http://masonry.desandro.com/ http://www.wookmark.com/jquery-plugin
- http://isotope.metafizzy.co/
- http://suprb.com/apps/nested/
- http://yconst.com/web/freetile/

No credit to me, as this info came off a search - hopefully it puts us in the right direction by studying the article and the javascript libs to see what is going on and find the simplest implementation for your job.

Comment: Answer perhaps a tab glib - Have bookmarked the question to see if this helps at all.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible css solution. Basically I'm making the large boxes cover the small ones, and making them layout-neutral.

```
.bigsq {
    width: 20%;
    height: 20%;
    background: red;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: -20%;
    margin-right: -20%;
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sabof/6H5ex/

Comment: This is a good workaround except that it'll overlay existing SmallBoxes. But in my case it'll work since the boxes content will be images and they are not in any strict order to show, so I can afford to hide a couple of them :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution would be possible using [jQuery Nested](http://suprb.com/apps/nested/).
Here is how your code would look like:

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="box size11"></div>
  <div class="box size12"></div>
  <div class="box size21"></div>
  <div class="box size22"></div>
  ...
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$("#container").nested({selector: '.box'});
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure what you mean, but try this

```
#big {
    float:left;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:gray;
    border-top-left-radius:10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:10px;
}

#small {
    float:left;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:gray;
    border-top-right-radius:10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:10px;
}
```